# What did the French resistance call the oil used to destroy German tanks/trucks?

Tags: world-war-two

I was told that isn't what the French resistance called it

What was the substance the French resistance added to the German tanks and trucks that caused the engines to blow
The resistance called it mostly because it looked like what? 
What was the French resistance name for this oil

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Your phrasing is hard to understand, but one substance that was used is "Caccolube," a thin rubber sac containing a gritty mixture, which wrecked engines after engine oil dissolved the rubber. Here's a [historical film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IlPOMsOmjY) about how to use it.

Another sabotage device was the "Firefly", an explosive device to be put in vehicle gasoline tanks. Again, here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fighcwoSB_I).

Edit: The French Resistance would probably not have had a standard term for it. They did not, after all, have a standard training system or ordinary military paperwork.

Comment: If [this report](http://www.ossreborn.com/files/War%20Report%20of%20the%20OSS%20Volume%201.pdf) is right, Caccolube was also known as "Turtle Eggs".

Comment: @DaltonHoward: Added a paragraph on that.